# Species Identification

Tags: species-identification

[image]
I found this in my hair this morning! Yucko! Please help me identify it. I have tried and tried to no avail.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What size is this? And where in the world are you located?

Comment: This appears to be an insect head; without the rest of the animal any identification is going to be suspect.